# How to change values of div when press key down

Tags: javascript, function, addeventlistener, arrow-keys

I have made divs in my HTML that I use to draw bars with CSS.
Now I want the to values change when the user presses the down arrow key.

This is my JavaScript:

```
var changeIdValue = function(id, value) {
document.getElementById(id).style.height = value;
};

window.addEventlistener("onkeydown", function(e){
if(e.keyCode == 40){
    changeIdValue("balklongwaarde", "60px");
});
}
```

I don't understand why this is not working.

Comment: Start simpler. Debugger line in the body of you function; does it ever trigger. [Follow the MDN example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onkeydown)

Comment: Use jQuery http://jquery.com/ instead, it is much simpler to have JavaScript listeners with jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can say something like this

```
window.onkeydown = function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 40)
            changeIdValue("balklongwaard", "60px");
        };
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this has been answered already, but if you want to follow your original idea, here's the correct code (because Mritunjay's answer only works for one usage per page).

```
var changeIdValue = function (id, value) {
        document.getElementById(id).style.height = value;
    };
window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 40) {
        changeIdValue('balklongwaarde', '60px');
    }
});
```

1. addEventListener is written with a capital L in Listener
2. 'onkeydown' should be 'keydown' when used with the addEventListener function
3. You closed your brackets in the wrong order (close if, close function, close function call)